# Send Rgba color value from js to controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to achieve something very interesting for my project. My form simply asks users to select color value in hex. After getting this value into JS, my code converts the value into Rgba format. Now I want to send this value to my controller to save into database.

I'm stuck over logic that how would I store results into variable and send it to controller. Let me share my working code the and the logic I'm trying to implement but no results.

Blade

```
<form>
   <input type="color" id="bgcolor" name="bgcolor">
   <button onclick="hex2rgb()">CLick</button>
</form>
```

Working JS script

```
  function hex2rgb(hex) {
      var hex = document.getElementById("bgcolor").value;
console.log(hex);
      r = hex.match(/^#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$/i);
      if (r) {
          return alert(r.slice(1, 4).map(function (x) {
              return parseInt(x, 16);
          }));
      return null;
  }
```

Trying to send value

```
  function hex2rgb(hex) {
      var hex = document.getElementById("bgcolor").value;
console.log(hex);
      r = hex.match(/^#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$/i);
      if (r) {
          return alert(r.slice(1, 4).map(function (x) {
              return parseInt(x, 16);
          }));

    var _token = {{csrf_token()}};
          $.ajax({
              url:"{{ route('niceActionController.multiStepStore') }}",
              method:"POST",
              data:{ _token:_token},
              success:function(result)
              {
                  console.log('successfully send');
              }

          })
      }

      return null;
  }
```

Laravel 6. PHP 7.4.

Comment: add paramater in data from your post

Comment: @Saromase
That's my question, How would I add variable into data ?

Comment: you data is an object, you only need to add attribute.
``` data : { _token : _token, hex : hex}```

Comment: @Saromase
I'm getting this error on button click.
""hex2rgb is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick""

Comment: if you add console.log() at the begin of the file, you have a log ?

Comment: @Saromase I noticed one thing. If I remove ajax snippet. Code works fine for me. Strange

Answer (score 0):

Send the converted value to the AJAX part. In side the data property, add 1 more value next to _token.

Comment: I know,I need to pass one more variable but I'm not able to store desired value  that I would send to data.

Comment: Why not? You already converted the value to RGBA didn't you? Store the converted value in a variable, then send that variable to data property.

Comment: How would I store the converted value into variable?
I tried to store but I always get warnings like "variable undefined".

Comment: I think you need to update a little bit and try to test again. First, remove the onclick event and instead, add a class or an ID. Then use jQuery to trigger hex2rgb function when button is clicked. The function doesnot need any param, just declare a variable called hex, and also you forgot to declare the r variable.

Comment: Declaration of r variable is not an issue because code is working fine. 
Only the issue is I need to pass variable into data and i don't know how would I do that. 
On adding ajax code into my script, error says "hex2rgb not defined".